# JSON Mapping to Object thats not 1 to 1

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a JSON response into an object that doesn't map 1 to 1.  The JSON that I am trying to deserialize is

```
{
"CustomerID": "1",
"CustomerName": "John Doe",
"BillingAddressLine1": "1234 Main St",
"BillingAddressLine2": "APT. 5",
"BillingCity": "New York City",
"BillingState": "NY",
"BillingZip": "12345",
"BillingCountry": "USA",
"BillingAttention": "John Doe",
"MailingAddressLine1": "555 Main St",
"MailingAddressLine2": "P.O. Box 5",
"MailingCity": "New York City",
"MailingState": "NY",
"MailingZip": "12345",
"MailingCountry": "USA",
"MailingAttention": "Jane Doe"  
}
```

and the objects I am trying to deserialize it to is

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID{ get; set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "CustomerName")]
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Address BillingAddress{get; set;}
    public Address MailingAddress{get; set;}
}
public class Address
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Attention { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way that this can be mapped by using Newtonsoft JSON deserializer or will this require a custom mapping function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nayr,

1. First, better use http://json2csharp.com/ to generate an object one-to-one with the Json.
2. Parse Json into this object.
3. Call a second method that parse Json-like-object into your's objects.

Simple, a bit not-nice, but keep the KISS...